# Searching through hashmap with object as a key

Tags: java, hashmap

I was searching through various topic but did not find any solution that would be suitable for my case.

Let's assume I need to store following values: 
(1) *product_id* (2) *segment_id* (3) *some_value*.

The combination of (1) and (2) is unique. To make it clear let me draw a simple table:

```
| product_id | segment_id | some_value|
---------------------------------------
|      1     |      1     |    100    |
|      1     |      2     |    200    |
|      2     |      1     |    300    |
|      2     |      2     |    400    |
```

I have decided to use Map with the key as combination of (1) and (2). The class that implements the key is as follows (comes from some other topic):

```
class MarketKey {

    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public MarketKey(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof MarketKey)) return false;
        MarketKey key = (MarketKey) o;
        return x == key.x && y == key.y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = x;
        result = 137 * result + y;
        return result;
    }

}
```

Putting values to the map works perfectly fine. Now, I want to search through the keys and sum up *some_value* for particular *product_id*, which is part of the key. That would be easy if I knew the range of *product_id* and *segment_id* but I don't.

The question I'm asking myself is whether a map is a good choice. I have chosen it because I wanted to make sure that I don't have double entries of combination of *product_id* and *segment_id* but this killed my ability to search through the elements of the key.

Any hint how to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Some answers below pointed out to use map of maps with *product_id* as a key. From java doc:

> A map cannot contain duplicate
>   keys; each key can map to at most one value.

If my understanding is right, *product_id* would have to have unique values and in my example this is not the case.

Comment: why don't you use `map` as value of the initial `map` say for example `HashMap<string,HashMap<string,value>>`

Comment: can you use one more map with product_id as key and list of MarketKey as values? Then given a product_id, you pick all the MarketKeys and count their values.

Comment: But product_id itself is not unique and as such shouldn't be used as a key. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @andarilhoPL, your update shows you misunderstand what several answers have suggested.  You can use your product id as a map key, provided that the associated map *values* are some kind of aggregate data structure.  In particular, they can themselves be maps from segment ids to the ultimate values.  This way you have to perform a double lookup to get individual values, but they are pre-grouped by product id.  This is not the only viable alternative, of course.

Comment: Thanks, I got it eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question I'm asking myself is whether a map is a good choice. I have chosen it because I wanted to make sure that I don't have double entries of combination of product_id and segment_id but this killed my ability to search through the elements of the key.
>
> Any hint how to implement this?

You could use a map of maps.  The top level map uses `product_id` for its keys, and each member map uses `segment_id`.

Alternatively, you could define a key order based first on `product_id` and then `segment_id`, and use a `SortedMap`.  `SortedMap.subMap()` would then be convenient for the kind of per-product scan you describe.

**Update:**

The main advantage of a `SortedMap` for this kind of task is simplicity of implementation and use.  The submap views provided by `headMap()`, `tailMap()`, and `subMap()` would serve as a convenient way to approach the type of problem the OP presents:

```
for (ValueType v : map.subMap(
        new MarketKey(pid, Integer.MIN_VALUE),
        new MarketKey(pid + 1, Integer.MIN_VALUE)).values()) {
    // ... do something with v
}
```

, yet with this approach you can still access elements via a single key:

```
map.put(new MarketKey(pid, sid), myValue);
```

If the data size has a fixed bound or if this is not a performance-critical section of the program then that's pretty much the end of the story.  On the other hand, if the program needs to perform operations such as you describe on its critical path, and if the data may be very large, then you need to consider performance.  Average performance for insertions, individual retrievals, and removals on a `SortedMap` will scale less efficiently (`O(log n)`) than for a `HashMap` or a `HashMap` of `HashMap`s `(O(1))`.  This is a necessary consequence of the sorted nature of a `SortedMap`, not depending on its particular implementation.

How behavior scales for iterating all items having a given product ID is a trickier analysis, depending in part on how the number of `segment_id`s per `product_id` scales with the number of `product_id`s.  No matter what, there is an `O(log n)` cost for the first entry for the `SortedMap` case, compared to `O(1)` for a `HashMap`, but after that each remaining one can be obtained for a fixed incremental cost.  If the number of segment IDs scales with the number of product IDs then the cost of iterating through the second and subsequent elements dominates, and the overall operation is `O(n)` in each case.  If the number of segment IDs is fixed, on the other hand, then the `HashMap` case is `O(1)` overall, but the `SortedMap` case is `O(log n)`.

Comment: +1 for suggesting `SortedMap`. Would be interesting to hear about pros/cons for nested vs. sorted Map approach, as I've never compared it directly in practice.

Answer (score 1):

`Map` is a good choice, but it would make sense to use a `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>` where the keys of the outer map are the product ids and the keys of the inner maps are the segment ids.

To get a "some_value" you would have to do

```
outerMap.get(productId).get(segmentId);
```

(Actually it's a bit more complicated than that as you would need to check for `null` to avoid a `NullPointerException`).

The advantage is that you can easily sum the values for a particular product id:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int someValue : outerMap.get(productId).values())
    sum += someValue;
```

I believe Guava has a `Table` interface that takes the pain out of using this kind of construction, but I've never used it. It may be worth looking it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop on the entry set of the map and sum up the value when the key meets your criteria (in the following code, I took the assumption that `some_value` is an integer):

```
Map<MarketKey, Integer> map = getMap();
int sum = 0;
for (Map.Entry<MarketKey, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getKey().getX().equals(productId)) {
        sum += entry.getValue();
    }
}
System.out.println(sum);
```